# Команда php artisan migration не создает таблицу в базе данных, а выдает fatal error

Tags: php, laravel

PHP Fatal error:  Uncaught UnexpectedValueException: The stream or file "/var/www/projects/targetspanish.com/storage/logs/laravel.log" could not be opened: failed to open stream: Permission denied in /var/www/projects/targetspanish.com/vendor/monolog/monolog/src/Monolog/Handler/StreamHandler.php:107
        Файл миграции:0

```
use Illuminate\Database\Schema\Blueprint;
use Illuminate\Database\Migrations\Migration;

class CreatePZostsTable extends Migration
{
/**
 * Run the migrations.
 *
 * @return void
 */
public function up()
{
    Schema::create('p_zosts', function (Blueprint $table) {
        $table->increments('id');
        $table->string('title')->nullabble();
        $table->string('slug')->unique();
        $table->text('exerpt')->nullabble();
        $table->text('content')->nullabble();
        $table->timestamps('published_at')->nullabble();
        $table->boolean('published')->default(false);
        //$table->rememberToken();
        $table->timestamps();
    });
}

/**
 * Reverse the migrations.
 *
 * @return void
 */
public function down()
{
    Schema::drop('p_zosts');
}
}
```

Comment: Все очевидно, проверьте права на папку storage/logs дайте им права на запись

Comment: спасибо, теперь выдает ошибку, что таблица уже создана....((((
 [PDOException]                                                                         
  SQLSTATE[42S01]: Base table or view already exists: 1050 Table 'users' already exists

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1) Первая ошибка возникла из за проблем доступа к файлу storage/logs

2) У вас создалась таблица users но с ошибкой, зайдите в базу и убейте ее.

Работает это так: происходит попытка создать таблицу, если таблица создается успешно, она записывается в таблицу migrations. 
При следующем вызове migrate в таблице migrations идет проверка были ли вызов миграций, если есть миграции которых нет в таблице они выполняются.

Но если у вас была ошибка, и таблица при этом создалась, но в таблицу migrations не попала. Отсюда и конфликт.

совет на будущее:

`php artisan migrate:rollback` - откатывает одну мигруцию (по неомеру в таблице migrations, если с одним номером несколько таблиц откатит все, начинает с самого большого номера)

`php artisan migrate:refresh`  - обновляет все таблицы (сносит и создает по новой)

`php artisan make:model -m City` - создаст модель и миграцию для нее

Comment: range_shadow , спасибо!!!!
решил с самого начала.....убил таблицу юзер и создал новую модель командой: 
        php artisan make:model -m City
после написал: php artisan migrate
выдало ошибку:
        [Symfony\Component\Debug\Exception\FatalThrowableError]  
  Call to a member function nullabble() on null    

потом пользуясь откатом миграции (php artisan migrate:rollback), использовал команду: php artisan migrate:refresh
но результат-та же ошибка :Call to...
 таблица users создается и еще создалась таблица password_resets, которой раньше не было, а вот таблица City не создалась...

Comment: @Александр  ну так вы пишите внимательнее :) nullabble пишется с одной b :) а вторая таблица это для восстановления паролей

Comment: это НЕ ко мне претензии!!!!! я скопировал ошибку из консоли PHPStorm'а и она вывелась вот в таком виде: [Symfony\Component\Debug\Exception\FatalThrowableError]  
  Call to a member function nullabble() on null  
а НЕ я сам придумал...я нашел этот файл FatalThrowableError.php там везде aBle без удвоенной ВВ

Comment: @Александр это у тебя ошибка в миграциях где-то. в какой то файле ты написал nullabble